# intent putExtra (при отправке в другое активити к числовому значению спереди добавляется нолик)

Tags: java, android

```
intent.putExtra("cena_bolshaya", cena_bolshaya.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("bludo", bludo.getText().toString());
```

Есть два textview, в одном число в другом текст, при отправке в другое активити в  `cena.setText(cena_bolshaya.getText().toString()+txtName);`
откуда-то берется ноль спереди, там где текст, то всё ок. Как убрать нолик в первом?

```
 cena=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_cena);
 bludo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_bludo);
 String txtName = getIntent().getStringExtra("cena_bolshaya");
 String bludoName = getIntent().getStringExtra("bludo");
 cena.setText(cena_bolshaya.getText().toString()+txtName);
 bludo.setText(bludo.getText().toString()+bludoName);
```

Comment: cena.setText(txtName); быть может вот так все-таки?

Comment: спасибо, работает.